# Present a View Modally below the tabview in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to build an app in SwiftUI. I need to present a fullscreen view on tapping the button in centre tab and dismiss the same on second click. The view needed should be above the tabview.

My ContentView is:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var index = 0
@State private var isPresented = false

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear
            switch self.index {
            case 0:
                Home()
            case 1:
                Info()
            case 2:
                Services()
            case 3:
                Support()
            case 4:
                Notifications()
            default:
                Home()
            }
        }
        CustomTabs(index: $index)
    }
}
```

}

My Custom TabView is:

```
struct CustomTabs: View {
@Binding var index: Int
@State private var showServiceView = false
@State var rotation = 0.0
@State private var isPresented = false

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        //Home
            VStack {
                Image("home")
                Text("Home").font(.system(size: 12))
            }
            .padding(.leading, 20)
            .frame(width: 55, height: 90)
        
        Spacer(minLength: 0)
        
        //Information
        VStack {
                Image("info")
                Text("Information").font(.system(size: 12))
            }
                         
        Spacer(minLength: 0)
        
        //Services
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 45)
                        .fill(Color.clear)
                        .frame(width: 90, height: 80)
                    Image(self.isPresented ? "closeTab" : "bottombutton")
                }
                Text("Services").font(.system(size: 12))
            }
            .offset(y: -30)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.index = 2
                self.isPresented.toggle()
            }
        
        Spacer(minLength: 0)
        
        //Support
        VStack {
                Image("support")
                Text("Support").font(.system(size: 12))
            }
        
        Spacer(minLength: 0)
        
        // Notifications
        VStack {
                Image(self.index == 4 ? "alertsSelected" : "tab_alert")
                Text("Alerts").font(.system(size: 12))
            }
    }
    .frame( height: 70)
    .background(Color.white)
}
```

}

I tried using

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
                //View2()
            })
```

and

```
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            //View2()
        })
```

this is giving the bottom sheet over the tabview

[image]

I need a bottom sheet like

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ZStack` for this purpose. With it, you can add the overlay underneath the `TabBar` and add a transition to the overlay, to present it like a modal.

Something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowingOverlay = false
    private let tabBarHeight: CGFloat = 100

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                if isShowingOverlay {
                    // Overlay
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(height: 400)
                        .padding(.bottom, tabBarHeight)
                        .transition(
                            AnyTransition.move(
                                edge: isShowingOverlay ? .bottom : .top
                            )
                        )
                }

                // TabBar
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: tabBarHeight)
                    .overlay {
                        Button(isShowingOverlay ? "Hide overlay" : "Show overlay") {
                            withAnimation {
                                isShowingOverlay.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

[image: modal animation]